# React | Gatsby: Components inside or outside main page component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-beautiful-dnd

While learning how to use `react-beautiful-dnd` library, I've found that (when I'm building the library required structure) if I define components outside the main app, it works on React but it does not work on Gatsby (development), it starts to work but then errors appear

But if I move those components inside the main app, then it also works on Gatsby

The example code:

```js
export default () => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState(myElements)

  const onDragEnd = result => {
    const { destination, source} = result

    if (!destination) return
    if (destination.droppableId === source.droppableId && destination.index === source.index) return

    const new_elements = reorder(elements, source.droppableId, destination.droppableId, source.index, destination.index)
    setElements(new_elements)
  }

  const Columns = ({ arr }) =>
    arr.map((col, i) => (
      <Droppable droppableId={col.columnId} key={i}>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <Ul ref={provided.innerRef}>
            <Elements arr={col.items} />
            {provided.placeholder}
          </Ul>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    ))

  const Elements = ({ arr }) =>
    arr.map((el, j) => (
      <Draggable draggableId={el.id} index={j} key={j}>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <Li ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
            {el.text}
          </Li>
        )}
      </Draggable>
    ))

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Grid>
        <Columns arr={myElements} />
      </Grid>
    </DragDropContext>
  )
}
```

So if `Columns` and `Elements` are defined outside, it's not working (but it is with React)

Why is this happening?

(the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-beautiful-dnd-with-hooks-bfwzl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: what's the error you're getting in gatsby?

Comment: `Unable to find draggable with id: `,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the docs https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/draggable.md#keys-for-a-list-of-draggable-

`Your key should not include the index of the item`

Once changed this, it works as expected

```
  <Droppable droppableId={col.columnId} key={col.columnId}>
  <Draggable draggableId={el.id} index={j} key={el.id}>
```